# Executing Javascript on Selecting Gridview Row then executing a Database query based on confirmation

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dom-events

I have a gridview that has the ability to select rows.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" SelectImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/Cross.png" SelectText="Cancel"/>
```

And I have it that if the user selects a row then it will execute a MySQL query to delete it from the database. This all works fine,
but I want the system to have a confirmation Javascript popup box when the user clicks on it. So they must confirm before the system executes the delete query.

```
 <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
     function confirm_proceed() {
         if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Cancel this booking?") == true)
             return true;
         else
             return false;
     }
 </script>
```

This is the Javascript I have but I cannot seem to get the system to execute it and the delete query.

Please Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the grid's RowDataBound event and attach the javascript onclick event:

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm_proceed();");
        }
}
```

Comment: That worked great Thanks. I just added the e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm_proceed();");
 line into my already existing RowDataBound method.

Answer (score 1):

Convert this field to Template field then the Code for LinkButton will appear in its template. Add the following attribute to the linkbutton `OnClientClick="return confirm_proceed();"`